# Optimize many to many tabular cube

Tags: ssas, ssas-tabular

I have a model that looks like the below, where we have sales transactions, then products, stores, and sales people.  In each case there's a many to many relationship, many sales have many types of products, many sales have many stores etc. Since the volumes are pretty high (38 million, 178 million, etc.) performance is our main issue.  How could we better design this model to facilitate faster performance? We've tried combining the Dimension into the bridge tables, which have helped. But using DAX Studio, we still see the sql joining out to the other tables is very costly.  Thanks for any advise.

[image]

Better performance but still queries taking 5-10 seconds when applying filters on all three tables:

[image]

Comment: Can you explain the grain of the "Sales Transactions" table, and why one row in that table relates to multiple PersonDim, multiple StoreDim and multiple ProductDim?

Comment: Thanks @DavidBrowne-Microsoft. The grain is one sale per row. Each sale can have multiple products purchased. Each sale can have multiple Stores involved, and each sale can have multiple sales reps associated with it.